# Javascript ES6 spread operator on undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, spread-syntax

While developing my react App, I needed to send a conditional prop to a component so I found somewhere a pattern to do so, although it seems really weird to me and I couldn't understand how and why it worked.

If I type:

```
console.log(...undefined)   // Error 
console.log([...undefined]) // Error
console.log({...undefined}) // Work
```

When the spread operator is activated on undefined an error is raised, although when the undefined is inside an object, an empty object returned.

I'm quite surprised regarding this behavior, is that really how it supposed to be, can I rely on this and is that a good practice?

Comment: I think anything that relies on an Iterator will throw with `null` or `undefined` because there's no way to implement the required methods on those values. I don't know why the object spread syntax works.

Comment: Come to think of it, I guess it makes sense that Object literal spread syntax doesn't fail, since what it's spreading is often another plain object, and those aren't Iterators by default, so they almost have to make an exception in that case.

Comment: `{...undefined}`  This won't even compile with Babel, so not something I would use.

Comment: Actually scrap that, it needs `stage-0`  so I assume is not ES6.. Is this spread feature going to be ES7?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This behavior is useful for doing something like **optional spreading**:

```
function foo(options) {
  const bar = {
    baz: 1, 
    ...(options && options.bar) // options and bar can be undefined
  } 
}
```

And it gets even better with [optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining), which is in `Stage 4` now (and already [available in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) 3.7+):

```
function foo(options) {
  const bar = {
    baz: 1, 
    ...options?.bar //options and bar can be undefined
  } 
}
```

*a thought*: its too bad it doesn't also work for spreading into an array

Comment: is the only solution to optionally spread `...options || {}` ?

Comment: You can do optional spreading into an array like this: `[...(options?.bar ? [options.bar] : [])]`. Not as elegant as with an object, but works well.

Comment: A short-hand for arrays that also works is `[...(options?.bar || [])]`

Comment: How about this one [...(options?.bar ?? [])]